# ValueError: need more than 2 values to unpack in Python 2.6.6

Tags: python

i am getting error: ValueError: need more than 2 values to unpack
when i run the unit test now, so 2 failures and one skip
now as far as i have read about

```
lambda i: get_error_count(self._error_lookup, i))
```

line 142 of source is the method

```
for test, err, capt in errors:
```

which has the line of code:

```
count = get_error_count(i)
```

**reference**
Python 3.0 has something a bit like this. Excess values can be bound
(as a list) to the last variable:

a,b,*c = [1,2,3,4,5]

will result in c containing [3,4,5].

In Python 2.x, you can't do that directly, but you should be able to
create a function that lengthens or shortens an input tuple of arguments
to the correct length so you can do:

```
a,c,b = fix(1,2)
d,e,f = fix(1,2,3,4)
```

However, the function won't know the length of the left hand side
sequence, so it will have to be passed in as an extra parameter or hard
coded.

so the

```
count = get_error_count(i)
uses only one variable, where as
def get_error_count(lookup, index):
takes on 2
```

What should i use as the second variable ? to fix this ?

Thanks,
-Kamal.

-------------------- >> begin captured stdout << ---------------------

\
    test_many_errors.test_assert_one ... FAIL
    test_many_errors.test_one ... ok
    test_many_errors.test_assert_two ... ERROR
    test_many_errors.test_two ... ok
    test_many_errors.test_value_one ... ERROR
    test_many_errors.test_value_two ... SKIP: (, ValueError(), )
    test_many_errors.test_good_one ... ok
    test_many_errors.test_good_two ... ok

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/Current/bin/nosetests", line 10, in <module>
    sys.exit(run_exit())
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/6.3/lib/python2.6/site-packages/nose/core.py", line 117, in __init__
    **extra_args)
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/6.3/lib/python2.6/unittest.py", line 817, in __init__
    self.runTests()
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/6.3/lib/python2.6/site-packages/nose/core.py", line 196, in runTests
    result = self.testRunner.run(self.test)
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/6.3/lib/python2.6/site-packages/nose/core.py", line 63, in run
    result.printErrors()
  File "/NOSE_TRIM/nosetrim-read-only/nosetrim/nosetrim.py", line 136, in printErrors
    lambda i: get_error_count(self._error_lookup, i))
  File "/NOSE_TRIM/nosetrim-read-only/nosetrim/nosetrim.py", line 142, in printErrorList
    for test, err, capt in errors:
ValueError: need more than 2 values to unpack
```

/

--------------------- >> end captured stdout << ----------------------

---

Ran 3 tests in 1.263s

Answer (score 20):

Instead of unpacking in your assignment:

```
a, b, c = do_something()
```

Try assigning the result to a single variable and testing its length:

```
t = do_something()
# t is now a tuple (or list, or whatever was returned) of results
if len(t) > 2:
    # Can use the third result!
    c = t[2]
```

Answer (score 2):

So `errors` is a list that contains items that are tuples of length 2 or 3.  You want a way to unpack tuples of varying length in a for-loop.  As you have noted, there is no clean way to do this in Python2.  Rather than coming up with a clever way of implementing this behavior, I would suggest making sure that your errors list always contains tuples of length of 3.  This can be done every time you add an item to `errors`, or after the fact, like this:

```
errors = [(x[0], x[1], x[2]) if len(x) == 3 else (x[0], x[1], None) for x in errors]
```

Or you could make a generator (which goes against my advice of not finding clever way to implement this behavior):

```
def widen_tuples(iter, width, default=None):
    for item in iter:
        if len(item) < width:
            item = list(item)
            while len(item) < width:
                item.append(default)
            item = tuple(item)
        yield item
```

Use it like this:

```
>>> errors = [(1, 2), (1, 2, 3)] 
>>> for a, b, c in widen_tuples(errors, 3):
...     print a, b, c
1 2 None
1 2 3
```

Answer (score 1):

You could write a utility function to make your results uniform:

```
def do_something2():
    return 1, 2

def do_something3():
    return 1, 2, 3

def do_something5():
    return 1, 2, 3, 4, 5

def uniform_result(*args):
    return args[0], args[1], args[2:]

a, b, c =  uniform_result(*do_something2())
print a, b, c
# 1 2 ()

a, b, c =  uniform_result(*do_something3())
print a, b, c
# 1 2 (3,)

a, b, c =  uniform_result(*do_something5())
print a, b, c
# 1 2 (3, 4, 5)
```

Answer (score 1):

I suggest complementing the list to the necessary length with the `None` elements:

```
data = give_me_list()
(val1, val2, val3) = data + (3 - len(data)) * [None]
```

3 is the number of the left hand side values. If the list can have excessive elements, then use protection against that:

```
data = give_me_list()[:3]
(val1, val2, val3) = data + (3 - len(data)) * [None]
```