# Handle differing number of returned variables

Tags: python

I am looking for handling differing number of returned values from invoked functions in a set number of target variables. The following simplified snippet is a starting illustration:

```
def f1(): return 1,2,3

def f2(): return 4,5

a,b,c = f1()

a,b,c = f2()  # How to massage this call: default of some sort?
```

So the objective would be to unpack *either* 2 *or* 3 results into three output variables.

Consider that the `f()` being invoked may be one of (many functions..)  that mostly all return only two variables .. but there is a need to add a third parameter to maybe one or two of them.

The motivation here: an existing codebase that presently returns only two variables. But I need to add a third one. It would be helpful to leave the existing code mostly alone and simply handle the missing third parameter gracefully.

What construction could be used here?

Comment: The question is about unpacking *either* 2 *or* 3 results into three output variales. `f1` and `f2` are representatives of an existing code structure that has many functions each of which handles a specific case and each returns two result values.  The `a`, `b` (and wishfully `c`)  are the returned values that are used in the ensuing logic.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Generally, you could save all of the returned values to a single variable and then access them using indexing.

```
x1 = f1()  # x1[0] = 1, x1[2] = 2, etc.
x2 = f2()
```

#### For Python 3:

If you need to use `a,b,c` for separate pieces of code, you can pack the variables using:

```
a,b,*c = f1()
a,b,*c = f2()
```

This will capture all values beyond the first 2 returned by `f1` or `f2` as a list in `c`.

#### Any python:

If you are in version 2.7, you can take a few extra steps to ensure assigning `c` doesn't give an error.  You capture the output of your function as a list, then extend the list to the length of your variables using `None`.  After that, you can assign directly to `a,b,c`

```
# assumes you have 3 variables: a,b,c
res = list(f2())
res += [None]*(3-len(res))
a,b,c = res
```

Comment: ah - is that a python 3.x construct? I'm on 2.7 and interpreter seems unhappy with the `*c`

Comment: Yes, this is python 3.

Comment: Ok - any suggestions for my antiquated 2.7 ;)  I'm probably going to need to do the indexing thing methinks..

Comment: added stuff for 2.7

Comment: Ya - I did something along those lines already. Thanks for fleshing that out - for future readers.

Answer (score 1):

You are unpacking the result of those two functions, instead of doing that perhaps you could assign the result to a single variable then test that for length. much like here: [ValueError: need more than 2 values to unpack in Python 2.6.6](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5515859/valueerror-need-more-than-2-values-to-unpack-in-python-2-6-6)

```
t = list(f2())
if len(t) > 2:
    # Can use the third result!
    c = t[2]
```

Comment: your answer and the one by james both mention the indexing - which is probably what I'll need to do.  His has an actually perfect result - but only for python 3.